# Join return only single row

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

We have a table called category_merchants where merchants are assigned categories.

**category_merchants**

```
unique_id     category_id     merchant_code
------------------------------------------
1             1               SS64007160
5             1               SS64008089
6             1               SS64000775
```

All I want to do is get all merchants from the "category_merchants" table who have a category_id of "1". I need to join on the merchants table to grab the merchant name for each.

**merchants**

```
id     merchant_num     merchant_nm
-------------------------------------
892    SS64000775       Ashburton Dressage
2024   SS64007160       Amuri A & P Association
2372   SS64008089       Ashburton A & P Association
```

I tried the following query, which I thought would return three rows, but only returns one.

```
SELECT cm.*, me.merchant_nm 
FROM category_merchant_t cm 
JOIN merchant_t me on me.merchant_num = cm.merchant_code 
and cm.category_id = 1
```

[image]

I guess I'm not understanding something. I need all three rows from category_merchants, with the merchant_nm from the merchants table appended to each row.

Comment: Your query ***does*** return 3 rows: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3ff9122989b59dc8bcb4a5f934fa8ece). Provide us with a [mre], with your sample data as DDL and DML statements.

Comment: Probably a data quality problem.  Make sure your merchant_num/merchant_code doesn't have any non printable characters, like CR, LF etc.

Comment: You're right Wouter, thanks. Add an answer and I'll mark it correct.

Comment: If you *do* have data quality issues, then some foreign key constraints would stop that.